# problem deleting symlink on windows using python

Tags: python, function, directory, symlink

This is the code I have been trying to use to delete a symlinked folder I have created and for some reason I keep getting permission errors

```
    def delete_symlink(self):
        symlink_path = self.text_input3.get()  # Get the symlink location from Textbox 3
        symlink_path = str(symlink_path)
    
        # Verify deletion with a popup
        confirmation = messagebox.askyesno("Delete Symlink", f"Do you want to delete the symlink at:\n{symlink_path}?")
        if confirmation:
            try:
                # Check if the symlink exists
                if os.path.exists(symlink_path):
                    # Use the 'os.remove' function to delete the symlink
                    os.chmod(symlink_path, 0o666)
                    if os.path.exists(symlink_path):
                        os.remove(symlink_path)
                    if os.path.exists(symlink_path):                   
                        subprocess.call(["rm", symlink_path])
                    if os.path.exists(symlink_path)   
                        os.system("rm " + symlink_path)
                    messagebox.showinfo("Symlink Deleted", f"Symlink at {symlink_path} has been deleted successfully!")
                else:
                    messagebox.showwarning("Not Found", f"{symlink_path} does not exist.")
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred: {e}")
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("Deletion Cancelled", f"Deletion of {symlink_path} has been cancelled.")
```

The entire program is just to manage mod folders for a game and I really need to be able to create and delete symlinks on the fly

I have tried chmod opening through batch, removing through subprocess and direct cmd and through shutil but still to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated as I am out of ideas

Comment: Have you tried running python as administrator？

Comment: yeah I was starting the program from powershell as admin